# How to get rid of extra space at top and bottom of Android WebView app

Tags: android, android-webview

My Android app consists of only a full-height, full-width WebView container.  The problem is that it displays extra space above and below the WebView.  Confusingly, the extra spacing varies between different Android versions. Note that this is not blank space *inside* the WebView control (i.e. part of the web content), but *outside* of it.

I have already set margins and padding to 0 in activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
```

My styles.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

My dimens.xml:

```
<resources>
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
```

On stock Android 13 virtual device, I have this huge blank space at the bottom:

[image]

While on my Samsung Galaxy S21, I get extra space at both top and bottom, and a superfluous navigation bar that I don't want.

[image]

**How can I get rid this extra spacing and navigation bar?**  Note that I **don't** want to go completely full-screen and hide the notification bar at the top.  I just want the WebView to use every bit of display other than the notification bar.